# Project planning for a commercial wall

Tags: drywall, walls, project-planning

I am looking at adding a wall to a commercial space. I have not seen the space yet, and so the underlayment might be slab, subfloor or a finished (carpeted) space. I don't know yet. Framing will be steel stud with one regular steel door and one double door.

I assume there are 8 basic steps:

1. The attachment points have to be prepared, so for example, if there is an existing flooring, then the flooring has be taken up and removed. If there is a slab, it has to be checked for flatness, etc. [CARPENTER]
2. The wall has to be measured out and planned. [CARPENTER]
3. The wall and doors are framed. [CARPENTER]
4. The electrician comes and installs wiring for outlets, lights and security. [ELECTRICIAN]
5. The drywall is cut and screwed into the framing. Outlets are matched to cutouts. [LABORER]
6. The wall is taped and plastered. [PLASTERER]
7. Molding and doors are installed. [CARPENTER]
8. Everything is painted. [PAINTER]

Is that the basic sequence? Am I missing any key steps or have anything out of order?

My main concern is that I kind of have the carpenter going and coming and he depends on the timing of the electrician and plasterer. So, any tips to scheduling things so that long delays do not occur.

Another concern is that the carpenter will do something that will screw up the electrician or vice versa. Are there any key gotchas I need to watch so the carpenter does not do something that is going to anger the electrician?

Finally, the drywall cutting is kind of a grunt labor job and I have done that before, installing corner beading and stuff like that. Theoretically I could do the drywall myself, but if I hire somebody, what is a good way to get the right sort of person? Just hit it up on craigslist, "Wanted, 2 guys with experience installing drywall. $20/hour" or something like that?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

1) Planning: You'll need a plan drawn to scale to get a Building Permit. Also, the plan will need to be stamped by an Architect, if the building you are going in is 4,000 sf or more, or if the building is more than 20' high.

2) Permits: Plan on a minimum of 4 weeks to get the plan reviewed and approved by the Planning and Building departments. After the Building Permit is issued you can start work. (The planning department may require a parking plan to assure them there is adequate parking for you to add your business, I.e.: a restaurant will require more parking than a gift shop.)

3) Demo: If there's any demo work you'll need an asbestos test completed and a report to give to your contractor's. (They won't work without assurance that the work site is certified "asbestos free".)  So, be sure to get a certificate from the abatement contractor that "all the asbestos has been removed in the area where you'll be working and the air is asbestos free," so you and your workers can return to the site. (Some jurisdictions require a report identifying lead-based paint too.)

4) Certificate of Occupancy: After the work is complete, you can't occupy the space until the local Building Official issues the Certificate of Occupancy...and you don't want to occupy the space early because your insurance is "void" without it.

Oh, by the way, you can't do any of the work yourself (including removing the asbestos, if any) unless you're a licensed contractor. I own my building and I can't work on it because I don't have a contractor's license. (Oh, in most jurisdictions you can do things that do not require a Building Permit, (i.e.: paint, carpet, etc.) But check with the local Building codes office. It's different in each jurisdiction.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're downplaying the importance of a good sheet rocker, it is a trade for a reason. The better the sheet rocker three less compound and skim coating that will have to be done. It effects the painter because it becomes flash points etc,  you also will need to repair the flooring and tie in the wall to the exciting ceiling. If it is not suspended ceiling then you will have to paint it as well. In reference to scheduling your trades, if you're a residential contactor the scheduling is very similar. Be aware of osha stopping by more frequently.